# Embedding python in C++ : strange segmentation faults

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

(Sorry for the vague title but it shows how dumbfounded I am by the issue).

So I'm running Python code from a C++ program, following the approach described here : https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html.

Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    int i;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv); 
    PyObject *sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject *path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
    PyList_Append(path, PyString_FromString("."));
    pName = PyString_FromString((char*)argv[1]);
    /* Error checking of pName left out */

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, argv[2]);
        /* pFunc is a new reference */

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {   
            PyObject *pArgs = PyList_New(4);
            PyList_SetItem(pArgs,0,PyString_FromString("H-SAMPLE1-OH"));
            PyList_SetItem(pArgs,1,PyInt_FromLong(2));
            PyList_SetItem(pArgs,2,PyString_FromString("H-SAMPLE2-OH"));
            PyList_SetItem(pArgs,3,PyInt_FromLong(3));
            PyObject *arglist = Py_BuildValue("(O)", pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);

            for(int run = 0; run < 2; run++)
            { 
                std::cout << "begin" << std::endl;

                pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, arglist);
                //Py_DECREF(arglist);
                if (pValue != NULL) 
                {
                    int py_list_size = PyList_Size(pValue);
                    printf("list size = %d\n",py_list_size);
                    int sub_list_size = 0;
                    for(Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < py_list_size; ++i)
                    {
                        PyObject *pList = PyList_GetItem(pValue, i);
                        sub_list_size = PyList_Size(pList);  
                        if(PyList_Check(pList))
                        {
                            for(Py_ssize_t j = 0; j < sub_list_size; ++j)
                            {
                                PyObject *pListItem = PyList_GetItem(pList, j);
                                double pyNumber = PyFloat_AsDouble(pListItem);
                                std::cout << "pynumber ok" << std::endl;
                                Py_DECREF(pListItem);
                                printf("Result of call: %f\n", pyNumber);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("Not list!\n");
                        }  
                        Py_DECREF(pList);
                    }
                    Py_DECREF(pValue);
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "Else" << std::endl;
                    Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                    Py_DECREF(pModule);
                    PyErr_Print();
                    fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the toy Python code:

```
def test(a):
    print a
    return [[1.2,2.6],[4.7,5.6]]
```

Notice the main loop in the C++ code, iterating over the variable "run". It works like a charm when the code inside the loop is executed only once. If I try to run it more, only twice for example, it goes wrong, I get a segmentation fault. Apparently, the fault happens at line 61, when trying to perform

```
double pyNumber = PyFloat_AsDouble(pListItem);
```

I find it really strange. It works fine during the first execution, and then suddenly if doesn't manage to properly get something from pListItem anymore (although it does receive something it recognizes as a list of size 2 and seems to handle all other pyObject pointers correctly). Any idea about what is happening?

**To reproduce:**

I compiled as follow:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o ms2pip ms2pip.c -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

And then executed as follow:

```
$ ./ms2pip python_code test
(so ./executable < python_file_without_py_extension > < function_name >)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that [PyList_GetItem()](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html#c.PyList_GetItem) returns a borrowed references. So the problem is with calling `Py_DECREF()` with both `pList` and `pListItem`:

```
PyObject *pList = PyList_GetItem(pValue, i);
// ...
if(PyList_Check(pList))
{
    for(Py_ssize_t j = 0; j < sub_list_size; ++j)
    {
        PyObject *pListItem = PyList_GetItem(pList, j);
        double pyNumber = PyFloat_AsDouble(pListItem); // <-- Segfault in second iteration after released from first iteration.
        // ...
        Py_DECREF(pListItem); // <-- Bad, released in first iteration.
        // ...
    }
}
//...
Py_DECREF(pList); // <-- Bad, released in first iteration.
```

`pList` is a borrowed reference which you are not responsible for releasing with `Py_DECREF()`. Also, `pListItem` is also a borrowed reference. So on the first iteration, you release `pList` as well as each `pListItem` which is bad. On the second iteration, you grab `pList` and each `pListItem` which have all been released and treat them as though they are still stable which is not the case. Because you are accessing freed objects, the program could really fail or give bad results at any of the function calls involving them (e.g., `PyList_Size(pList)`, `PyList_GetItem(pList, j)`, `PyFloat_AsDouble(pListItem)`, `Py_DECREF(pListItem)`, `Py_DECREF(pList)`).

Comment: I commented out a few Py_DECREF statements and it seems to work fine now! But is it ok to just comment them out? Aren't they there for a reason? I must admit I don't fully understand their role (this code is based extensively on the one that can be found at the page I linked) but I would expect that if you don't use them, you hold on to memory resources and can run into memory problems, no?

Comment: @jerorx Have a read through [Objects, Types and Reference Counts](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/intro.html#objects-types-and-reference-counts) (especially the parts about referencing counting). In summary, when a `PyObject*` (or descendant) is returned from any `Py*` function, the documentation will indicate whether it is *borrowed reference*, or *owned (or new) reference*. A *borrowed* reference means you do not own the object, and will only use it temporarily. If you want to keep a reference to it, you must `Py_INCREF()` it so that you can later `Py_DECREF()` it.

Comment: @jerorx With an *owned* (or *new*) reference, you own it and must call `Py_DECREF()` when you are done with it otherwise its memory will leak.

Comment: @jerorx A general rule for how long you can use a *borrowed* reference is it's only valid so long as the containing object has not been modified and only use for the scope at which you acquired it (e.g., the reference from `PyList_GetItem()` is only valid until another call to `PyList_*` is performed). Some functions such as `PyList_SetItem()` will *steal* your references. So if you were to `PyList_GetItem()` an item (*borrowed* reference), and then `PyList_SetItem()` the item (*steals* the reference), you will have to `Py_INCREF()` the item in between to ensure the proper reference counts.